# Why am I unable to change read permissions with chmod?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chmod

If I type this in the terminal

```
chmod -R g+r "/media/truecrypt1/My folder/"*
```

and then check the result wiht

```
ls -l
```

I still get

```
-rwx------ 1 user user 127860 2012-03-16 15:45 sample.pdf
```

What's wrong?

I've also tried `sudo`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

chmod -R `g=r` "/media/truecrypt1/My folder/"*

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work

Comment: did you try with root user?

Comment: I've tried with sudo but nothing.

Comment: if your media is ntfs (apperantely it is) chmod or chown does not work for ntfs.You can mount your ntfs media manually with giving  exact permission.Something like

sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever